# Npm hangs during firebase-cli installation

Tags: firebase, npm

I am trying to install firebase-cli using terminal

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

but it gets stuck, I am able to install other npm packages successfully

Here is screen shot of detailed verbose

[image]

the last final error reads:

> error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM
> routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

this is where it gets stuck.

Comment: I am seeing same with npm install --safe firebase on Win 10

Comment: Could not figure out the issue, had to reinstall os :D

Comment: I just reissued command after closing and reopening command line